# Allow google sign-in/sign-up in my app without signing in for entire device

Tags: android, ios, authentication, google-signin, google-authentication

I have what I imagine to be a very unusual behaviour requirement for google-signin (as well as some other social auths). I have been unable to find a solution I am happy with. Basically we need to allow users to sign in and sign up with google but we do not want to have the user be logged into this account on their device. (We do not want them to be able to continue to authenticate into other apps with the google account they used for our app).

Is there any suggestions as to how something like this may be possible on Android and/or IOS. Currently I am looking at it if I can hack a POC together by having the google sign in button open a WebView within the app instead of using the native SDKs.

Comment: Why don't you just do the google sign-in, and then do google sign-out? You could store in a boolean wether the sign-in was made or not to "simulate" the sign-in in your app.